# Can curl localhost, but can't access port 80 from LAN

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables

I can't find an answer to this question anywhere.

I have ssh access set up, and can tunnel into my server. When on the server, I can curl localhost and get a response:

`curl localhost`

However, when I attempt to access port 80 on my LAN, I get no response.

I have edited IPTables to show:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` is accepting connections from anywhere destined to port 80, fine.

Based on the fact that you can `curl localhost` but NOT from another host within the LAN, I reckon the daemon running listens to loopback only, change it to listen on your NICs, for example eth0 and restart the service.

e.g.

Apache vhost config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Nginx vhost config file

```
server {
    listen   *:80;
    ...
}
```